# MySQL: carriage-return in query breaks my import

Tags: mysql, migration, export, aws-aurora

I use simple `echo "select * from tab" | mysql --batch --quick --skip-column-names .... > /tmp/file` from mysql to get data.

Then, import to postgres using `\copy tab FROM /tmp/file DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' NULL AS '\N' CSV`.

for the most part it works well up until a carriage-return value comes in a `text` field.

Something like(partial string):

```
id      error
122859  Error invoking external process   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current^M\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed^M\n^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M\ncurl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to file.fm:443 ^M\n<br>The error occurred on line 26 in file.
```

When `^M` comes it breaks my import, I was initially thinking this is import issue, but clearly it is the export (mysql) side.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031716/mysql-carriage-return-in-query) solution but I'm thinking if there is a more elegant solution that doesn't requires me to rewrite all my export queries. Also, replacing `\r\n` to `\n` doesn't solve all the problems in this output example.

Comment: Do you mean that in the export you have all raw `^J` chars (that are part of a column's data) replaced with `\n` and all raw `^M` chars kept as raw chars?

Answer (score 0):

If CR or CRLF is the line terminator, so state.  Don't assume LF is smart enough to include CR.

Comment: Sorry, not following. Are you saying just to replace `\r` to empty string? If so, won't I lose some valid characters in the process? For example: `error in log file C:\\System\\robinhood`

Comment: You might have misunderstood the issue. My guess is, it's to do with how text values are exported. Specifically my guess is, `\n`'s inside text values are exported escaped (as `\n` literals) while `\r`'s are exported raw, and that's what breaks the import.

Comment: @AndriyM - I don't recognize the syntax you are using.  I do know that `LOAD DATA` has a clause like `LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"`.  If that is somewhere that I don't see, you need to change it to `LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"`